# Magento 2.3.0 logo not uploaded due to deferred.pipe() console error

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Please check attachment. I have a fresh `Magento 2.3.0` installation. Unable to upload a logo.

The error says "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."

**Consol error**

> JQMIGRATE: deferred.pipe() is deprecated at
>   /adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-migrate.jsjquery-migrate.js:45

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is bug in Magento 2.3.0 because when you try same with product water mark image, it is not getting uploaded and thats why it is not showing old uploaded image there.

**Solution:**

In **vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml** file change **fileUploader** to **imageUploader** on line number **57** and **154**

Comment: Yes. All image upload except Magento product. This happened.

Comment: Yes, This works.

Comment: I have same problem but unable to solve using this. Any other thing i have to done?